# onClick toggleClass of td inner element and removeClass for sibling td inner elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

1), I want to toggleClass('unmuted') to a tag in tr td element 
2), When i click on another a tag in another tr td element remove class to the previous a tag and add class to the current element

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.unmuted{background: #ff0000;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table class="myTable" border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <a class="unmute" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/typicons-2/24/microphone-512.png" width="16"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <a class="unmute unmuted" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/typicons-2/24/microphone-512.png" width="16"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <a class="unmute" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/typicons-2/24/microphone-512.png" width="16"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".myTable").on('click','a', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('unmuted').closest('tr').find('a').removeClass('unmuted');
        //$(this).addClass('unmuted');
     })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you only ever want one element having class `unmuted`?

Comment: Yes but i also want that class to be toggle

Comment: How can you see your `unmuted` class (`color` CSS property) when your element just contains an image?

Comment: @Jeto for posting here I've added image actually I will be using fontawesome icon in place of that image

Comment: @Jeto I've changed it to 'background' now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select any element's that currently have a `unmuted` class along with the current element (by using [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/)) and call toggleClass on it. The ones, including the current element, that already have it will get toggled off, and any that dont will have it toggled on.

```js
$('.unmute').click(function(){
  $('.unmuted').add(this).toggleClass('unmuted');
});
```

```css
.unmuted {
  background:#ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="myTable" border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <a class="unmute" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/typicons-2/24/microphone-512.png" width="16"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <a class="unmute unmuted" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/typicons-2/24/microphone-512.png" width="16"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <a class="unmute" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/typicons-2/24/microphone-512.png" width="16"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is what am looking for Thank You so much @Patrick Evans.